# The bluetooth is disabled on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: bluetooth, services

This is probably a duplicate of 
[Bluetooth is disabled on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/465442/bluetooth-is-disable-on-ubuntu-14-04)

But the answers there did not help. I am struggling to add my device in bluetooth but all it shows are disabled options.

Is there a way? I checked all the bluetooth software and it is installed correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/67758/8005

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**To turn Bluetooth ON when your system starts up do the following:**

Open a Terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

Enter the following line if you don't have gksu installed.

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
```

If you have GKSU (installed or already have) enter the following:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

The `rc.local` file will open. Add the following line before the `exit 0`:

```
rfkill unblock bluetooth
```

Now enter the following line in a terminal:

```
sudo reboot
```

**To turn Bluetooth OFF when your system starts up do the following:**

Open a Terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

Enter the following line if you don't have `gksu` installed.

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
```

If you have GKSU (installed or already have) enter the following:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Add the following line above `exit 0`:

```
rfkill block bluetooth
```

Now enter the following line in a terminal:

```
sudo reboot
```

To switch between ON or OFF you can use the <kbd>FN</kbd>+Bluetooth key on your keyboard.  This key is different for each system.
You can change **bluetooth** also for something else, like **wireless**.

**How to install/update the Bluetooth drivers:**

Open a Terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

Enter:

```
sudo apt-get install bluez bluez-alsa bluez-audio bluez-btsco bluez-compat bluez-cups bluez-dbg bluez-gstreamer bluez-hcidump bluez-pcmcia-support bluez-tools bluez-utils python-bluez bluewho indicator-bluetooth libbluetooth-dev  libgnome-bluetooth11 libbluetooth3
```

Comment: Thanks, let me try by following these steps. And then I will let you know :)

Comment: why don't you just use `sudo gedit`, instead of `gksudo`?

Comment: santosh@santosh-Dell-System-Inspiron-N4110:~$ sudo apt-get install gksu -y
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Comment: this is what the error I got after running the first command - sudo apt-get install gksu -y   :'(

Comment: Try `gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local`

Comment: Awesome, it is amazingly working. Thank you soooooooooooooo much my friend. You are the man :) I could add my Bluetooth mouse even.

Comment: You're welcome, the answer gives you now some extra information.

Comment: But can you tell me why my bluetooth mouse connectivity is getting off automatically in ever 4-5 seconds if I don't use my mouse? I again have to switch it on in order to use the mouse again. very annoyed.

Comment: USB mouse? Try a other USB port.

Comment: no the bluetooth mouse which I added just now. Also I added the screenshot below.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14830/discussion-between-korkel-and-santu). - I updated the answer again.

Comment: installed a software, but that software doesn't work

Answer (score 14):

I use Ubuntu 14.04 on Lenovo Thinkpad X220.

I resolved this problem by running:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/sbin/bluetoothd
sudo service bluetooth restart
```

Comment: I worked for me on my HP Envy/  Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Such a brilliant suggestion! that's what eventually fixed it for me...

Answer (score 1):

if you love terminal then you will love this trick.

firstly open up terminal(ctrl+alt+t)
then type Bluetoothctl start

it will connect you to the Bluetooth shell ,and now you connect to Bluetooth

so ,you have to type devices to see how many devices are discoverable.

pick your device and start typing connect [device address] //here device address is located to just besides your device name.

enjoy your connection to Bluetooth via terminal.