# Bluetooth disabled and not showing up in LSPCI - ASUS G750JM

Tags: bluetooth, broadcom

The modem installed properly on 14.04, it worked on installation of ubuntu.  It's a Broadcom modem, and it's tied into the Broadcom bluetooth card.  But the bluetooth does not function on 14.04.  Ubuntu says it's disabled what can I do to fix this?  It doesn't say that it's not there, it just says disabled even after I turn it on.

```
rfkill list all
    0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
    1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
    2: asuswlan: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
    3: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: yes
        Hard blocked: no
```

UPDATE:
I removed asus-bluetooth's soft block by running the following commands:

```
$sudo modprobe -b asus-wmi
$rfkill unblock all
```

But it's still disabled in settings and I can't use it and it returns to being disabled after a short time

UPDATE:

```
$hcitool scan
Device is not available: No such device

$ lsmod | grep asus

asus_nb_wmi            16990  0 
asus_wmi               24191  1 asus_nb_wmi
sparse_keymap          13948  1 asus_wmi
wmi                    19177  2 mxm_wmi,asus_wmi
video                  19476  2 i915,asus_wmi
```

UPDATE:

```
$ lspci
    00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
    00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
    00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
    00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
    00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
    00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
    00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 05)
    00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
    00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
    00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d5)
    00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d5)
    00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev d5)
    00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05) 
    00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM87 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
    00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
    00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
    01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M] (rev ff)
    03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
    04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 10)
```

Am I to assume that since it doesn't list bluetooth anywhere in that list that Ubuntu just doesn't realize that I have a bluetooth device?  It would explain why I've tried virtually everything to enable it but it won't work.  Please help.

UPDATE:

Since upgrading to 14.10 bluetooth works as long as I `rfkill unblock all`

UPDATE:

and now since I removed ubuntu and reinstalled from scratch 14.10 it works fine without a hitch

Comment: run `rfkill unblock all` in terminal (press <Ctrl>+<Alt>+<T> to open)

Comment: please read my post over again i had it very poorly worded should i still try your rfkill unblock all?

Comment: yes try that...

Comment: still says bluetooth is disabled

Comment: see this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/474839/bluetooth-is-disable-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: why would this do anything?  we've already tried rfkill unblock bluetooth it doesn't enable my bluetooth

Comment: try with last option `"How to install/update the Bluetooth drivers:"`

Comment: it didn't help, but if you read the question again you'll see i'm making progress

Answer (score 0):

If you type "Bluetooth" in dash and open the Bluetooth App you will see something like below screen shot, it say

> Bluetooth is disabled

[image]

you need to run `rfkill unblock 3` and then go to Bluetooth app window and drag <kbd>ON/OFF</kbd> button to right side to turn Bluetooth `ON` and also if you want to have visible your Bluetooth device for other devices you need turn `ON` Visibility mode.

[image]

If you check in terminal with `rfkill list 3` you will see the Bluetooth device is now `ON`

```
3: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: it didn't work I did $rfkill unblock 3 then $rfkill list 3 and it still says asus-bluetooth is soft blocked

Comment: @daniel Do you a dual boot with windows?

Comment: yes i do dual boot with windows 7

Comment: Yes this is the problem. boot from your windows 7 and enable Bluetooth device there and then boot back to ubuntu. it will fix your issue.

Comment: bluetooth is enabled in windows 7

Comment: 'm try this `sudo hciconfig hci0 reset`

Comment: no such device.

Comment: no such file or directory

Comment: http://linuxhacks.in/2014/05/ubuntu-bluetooth-is-disabled.html

Comment: thanks for trying but that didn't work either, i edited it and rebooted then i even tried doing the rfkill unblock bluetooth too no dice

Comment: last option is: Report that as a bug or see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/554431. sorry.

Comment: no problem thanks for trying, i reported it...  it's funny though since i got this laptop i have had more problems with ubuntu than i ever expected and most of them i'm having to solve on my own cause there just isn't anything out there on it yet

Comment: This has been reported as a bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1366854