# Bluetooth option is gray and not activated

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth

My `HP-242 G1` Laptop is running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. My bluetooth is deactivated.
See the image:

[image]

result of running `dmesg | grep -i blue` in the terminal is :

```
[   16.233056] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.17
[   16.233078] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   16.233086] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   16.233089] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   16.233094] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   16.236555] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   16.236568] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   16.236572] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   16.329098] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   16.329102] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   16.329112] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

And, result for running `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb` is :

[image]

**What do I need to activate bluetooth now?**

Comment: Please edit question to add results for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb`

Comment: Look at the end of this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-lts-trusty/+bug/1355096) and see if it works.  I am doubtful and will not submit it as an answer

Comment: Check out http://askubuntu.com/questions/474839/bluetooth-is-disable-on-ubuntu-14-04. Simple edit to /etc/rc.local fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

It can be the Bluetooth kernel module was not loaded. Can you share `lsmod` command output? For example:

```
root@myvivid:~# lsmod | grep blue

bluetooth             491520  1 bnep
```

Comment: and make sure service bluetooth is running.

Comment: `bluetooth             391196  10 bnep,rfcomm` is the output of `lsmod | grep blue`

Comment: bluetooth is not working, then how I can be sure that, service bluetooth is running.

Comment: @partho Try `service bluetooth status` , if the service was down, try to starting it via `service bluetooth start`. If it still failing, try to take a look in `/var/log/syslog` for possible logging.