# How do I turn bluetooth on/off in ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: 15.10, bluetooth

I doesn't get any option in the bluetooth menu. Its like disabled. On every ubuntu version I try, 14 15 the bluetooth is always disabled. Can we use bluetooth in ubuntu?

Comment: may duplicated here !! http://askubuntu.com/questions/474839/bluetooth-is-disable-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 0):

Check if you've got the following packets installed:

- bluez-utils
- libopenobex1
- gnome-bluetooth
- blueman

If you are using an USB-device check if it is recognised correctly:

```
lsusb | grep Bluetooth
```

Also try runnig the following command to restart the bluetooth service:

```
sudo service bluetooth restart
```