# Bluetooth Controls are disabled in Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: bluetooth

I am not able to control the bluetooth activity in Ubuntu 16.10

I am using Compaq-15-Notebook intel i3.

Comment: add more details, are Bluetooth settings disabled or invisible? or you just can't pair a device?

Comment: `hcitool dev` give us the out put of this command

Comment: In control panel the Bluetooth controls are greyed oout. I am not able switch on the Bluetooth connection.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/474843/665251 try this out