# I cannot enable Bluetooth on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth

I bought a Bluetooth keyboard yesterday and I wanted to connect it with my computer but I am unable to enable it.

[image: screenshot of Bluetooth settings, showing "No Bluetooth adapter found"]

I have already tried [The bluetooth is disabled on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/474839/bluetooth-is-disable-on-ubuntu-14-04). I added `rfkill unblock bluetooth` before `exit 0` and rebooted but it did not help. And when I write `rfkill list` in my terminal, it shows nothing. I have also tried `sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth start` but this does not help either. What should I do?

Here is the output for the `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb`:

```
shalva@shalva-All-Series:~$ rfkill list
shalva@shalva-All-Series:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp.
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 3d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

[image: screenshot of terminal]

`rfkill list` is below in the picture. My computer is a desktop. I just this in terminal:

```
dmesg | grep Blue
```

But that showed nothing. Does this mean my computer does not have Bluetooth?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: Please post terminal output as text, not as screenshots. You ran a wrong command. It is not `rfkill lis`, but `rfkill list`. And what is "your computer" is it a desktop or a laptop? Does it have a bluetooth and a wireless adapter?

Comment: Your computer does not have a bluetooth adapter. PLEASE DO NOT POST SCREENSHOTS OF TEXT. You can copy text from a terminal and paste it as text.

Answer (score 2):

Your computer does not have a Bluetooth adapter. That is why you can't use Bluetooth devices.