# Bluetooth used to be enabled, now disabled and won't enable. Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth

The issue here, is, that, bluetooth *used* to work. It's not working at all anymore, and I'm unsure why. When I go into system settings and try to hit enable, it simply slides the little switch back to disabled. Attempting `sudo hciconfig hci0 reset` as listed in [bluetooth is disable on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/465442/bluetooth-is-disable-on-ubuntu-14-04) returns `Can't init device hci0: Connection timed out (110)`.

rfkill list returns:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

lspci -nnk returns:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller [8086:0c00] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller [1458:5000]
    Kernel driver in use: hsw_uncore
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0412] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [1458:d000]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:03.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller [8086:0c0c] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller [8086:2010]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI [8086:8c31] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI [1458:5007]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:8c3a] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller [1458:1c3a]
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:16.3 Serial controller [0700]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family KT Controller [8086:8c3d] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family KT Controller [1458:1c3a]
    Kernel driver in use: serial
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-V [8086:153b] (rev 05)
    DeviceName:  Onboard LAN
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Ethernet Connection I217-V [1458:e000]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 [8086:8c2d] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI [1458:5006]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller [8086:8c20] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller [1458:a002]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 [8086:8c10] (rev d5)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 [8086:8c16] (rev d5)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5 [8086:8c18] (rev d5)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 [8086:8c26] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI [1458:5006]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation H87 Express LPC Controller [8086:8c4a] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd H87 Express LPC Controller [1458:5001]
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] [8086:8c02] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] [1458:b005]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:8c22] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [1458:5001]
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:1091] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet [1458:e000]
    Kernel driver in use: alx
    Kernel modules: alx
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1] (rev 73)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 [8086:4070]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

If there's any more information you need, please simply ask!

Comment: any solution meanwhile? I have posted this: [Make permanent the bluetooth speaker access](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/405813/make-permanent-the-bluetooth-speaker-access)

Answer (score 46):

```
sudo rmmod btusb
sleep 1
sudo modprobe btusb
```

This worked for me. I found this solution [here](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/bluetooth-firmware-upload-failing-after-suspend/46940/6).

Comment: worked in Ubuntu 19.04 / GNOME 3.32.1

Comment: Worked in Ubuntu 18.04/ Gnome 3.28.2

Comment: Worked in Manjaro / Gnome

Comment: Worked in Ubundu 19.10 / GNOME 3.4.1

Comment: this just worked for me. Bluetooth stopped working after going from 19.10 to 20.04 (I have an asus b450 motherboard with built-in bluetooth)

Comment: I did fresh install of 20.04, bluetooth was working fine, but now it is not. I tried the above solution and it is not working for me. Any tips? @DennisdeBest

Comment: Why does this work? It did for me, but what is the issue, what do these commands repair?

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04. Brand new machine and was not able to enable bluetooth until I found this. I also tried the solution below (reinstalling bluez) and it did nothing.

Comment: Worked for 21.04!

Comment: This works but I have to do this every single time I need to open bluetooth, any way I can make this permanent?

Comment: worked for `Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS`.

Comment: It worked on Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bluez
```

Updated Answer:

- Disable and reenable your bluetooth device with the hard switch on your computer (switch or button)
- Go to 'System Settings' >> 'Bluetooth' and activate 'Show Bluetooth Status in the menu bar'...
- Set 'Bluetooth ON' in the menu bar and reboot your system...

Comment: Already tried this, sorry. Doesn't work.

Comment: what happens (with the slider) if you type in the terminal: rfkill unblock bluetooth? What happens if you type: sudo service bluetooth start?

Comment: rfkill unblock bluetooth would only do anything if bluetooth was blocked to begin with. Hold for start.

Comment: Just noticed that I have the same problem (after yesterdays update I guess)... I updated the answer above, now it works...

Comment: I, uh, can't disable the bluetooth device with the hard switch. It's actually on the board. I don't have a button to turn it off.

Comment: You sure have one, on many laptops it's combined with the wifi-switch on the keyboard...

Comment: Hm. Didn't work.

Comment: It did worked for me. Thank you Neni. I don't have a hard switch but it worked the Fn+F2 and after reboot the icon appeared and worked. Only the System Configuration >Bluetooth still have a small problem with the enable/disable device button

Comment: reinstalling broke stuff for me, and created a nightmare. Do not recommend.

Comment: this does nothing on my Latitude 3590 with Ubuntu Budgie 18.04

Answer (score 5):

This command seemed to work on a later version of Ubuntu (18.04 LTS).

```
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
```

and then enter your password.

Answer (score 2):

When I first added my bluetooth speaker, it was marked as blocked by soft in the list of `sudo rfkill list`.

After unblocking it with `sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth`, I was able to add it.

But after restart I am in the exact situation described in this question:

> When I go into system settings and try to hit enable, it simply
>   slides the little switch back to disabled

The device is not listed as blocked. After removing it and adding it again, it is sometimes blocked, but not always. Unblocking it again, it works.

I haven't found a quicker solution than to remove the device from the list, add it again, unblock it if necessary ...

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/405813/make-permanent-the-bluetooth-speaker-access

Answer (score 1):

I did all the suggested solutions above. Unfortunately, none worked. It seems a hardware problem to me because Bluetooth won't work also on my Windows-10 (dual boot). So I focus on searching for possible hardware solutions.

Then I ended up with the solutions below. I can't give a detailed explanation, but this really worked in my end.

---

1. plugged off my charging cable
2. do a hard shutdown
3. start the laptop again

---

credits to [<sup>heheman3000 (mizzao)</sup>](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1859592/comments/5)  for sharing this solution.